# Change data type of keys in array from numeric to string

Tags: php, arrays, data-conversion

I have two arrays with numeric keys. This is a small example:

```
$test_a = array(1 => 'one', 2 => '二');
$test_b = array(2 => 'two', 4 => 'four');
```

I want to merge them, with `array_merge()`, to receive `$test_c` array:

```
$test_c = array(
    1 => 'one',
    2 => 'two',
    4 => 'four'
);
```

The manual for [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge/) mentions that:

> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

what seems to be true, because this:

```
$test_c = array_merge($test_a, $test_b);
var_dump($test_c);
```

returns:

```
array (size=4)
    0 => string 'one' (length=3)
    1 => string '二' (length=3)
    2 => string 'two' (length=3)
    3 => string 'four' (length=4)
```

What did I try:

1. I tried casting keys as strings:

   ```
   foreach($test_a as $key => $value) $test_a[(string)($key)] = $value;
   ```

   ...keys are still numeric.
2. I tried with [`strval()`](http://php.net/array_merge/):

   ```
   foreach($test_a as $key => $value) $test_a[strval($key)] = $value;
   ```

   no change. Keys are still numeric.
3. I tried with this trick:

   ```
   foreach($test_a as $key => $value) $test_a['' . $key . ''] = $value;
   ```

   Does not work either. The keys are still numeric.

What surprised me, was when I found out that there is something like automatic conversion from string to numeric on array keys. This changed the keys to strings:

```
foreach($test_a as $key => $value) $test_a[' ' . $key . ' '] = $value;
```

and when I added `trim()`:

```
foreach($test_a as $key => $value) $test_a[trim(' ' . $key . ' ')] = $value;
```

the keys were converted back to numeric.

Basically, I want to merge these two arrays. I guess that the only solution is to find a way to convert the keys from numeric to string data type.
If you can additionally explain the "automatic conversion" thing then I will be fully satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `+` operator on both arrays, like so:

```
$test_a = array(1 => 'one', 2 => '二');
$test_b = array(2 => 'two', 4 => 'four');

var_dump( $test_b + $test_a);
```

This [will output](http://viper-7.com/F1jRi7):

```
array(3) {
  [2]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "four"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "one"
}
```

It's not in the exact order you're looking for, but you could use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort) to sort by the keys to [get the exact output](http://viper-7.com/61AYsv). What you're referring to as "automatic conversion" is actually called type coercion, and is referred to as [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, I did this:

```
foreach($new as $k => $v)
{
    $old[$k] = $v;
}
// This will overwrite all values in OLD with any existing
// matching value in NEW
// And keep all non matching values from OLD intact.
// No reindexing, and complete overwrite
// Working with all kind of data
```